# Google Docs API: "The insertion index cannot be within a grapheme cluster"

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm stumped by a 400-status when using the Google Docs API to write certain Unicode characters to a Google Doc:

> HttpError: https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/xxxxxxxxx:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid requests[0].insertText: The insertion index cannot be within a grapheme cluster.">

I've managed to boil this down to its smallest example.  The routine below attempts to insert (in order):

- The string of Thai characters `'ถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ'`
- A newline, above/before the string above

Code:

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
]

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file("data/gdocscredentials.json", scopes=SCOPES)
svc = build("docs", "v1", credentials=credentials).documents()

requests = [ 
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                #  The zero-based index, in UTF-16 code units
                "index": 1
            }, 
            "text": "ถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ"
        }
    },
    {"insertText": {"location": {"index": 1}, "text": "\n"}}

]
svc.batchUpdate(
    documentId="xxxxxxxxx",
    body={"requests": requests}
).execute()
```

So, the error alludes to the Thai string containing (or being) a grapheme cluster.  The [docs refer to this](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/rules-behavior):

> The API may implicitly adjust the location to prevent insertions within Unicode grapheme clusters. When this happens, the text is inserted immediately after the grapheme cluster.

**How do I properly correct this error**?

Google [mentions that](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text_) *indexes are measured in UTF-16 code units*. But that doesn't seem like it should matter here since this code snippet is using the 'work backwards' approach that is itself recommended by the same documentation page.

Answer (score 2):

How about this answer?

#### Issue and solution:

The characters of `ถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ` are 2 bytes. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. When a text is try to be put to the center of a 2-byte character, such error occurs.

From your request body, I thought that you want to put `ถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ` to the index `1` and then, you want to put the line break `\n` to the index `1`. In this case, `\nถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ` is the same situation.

#### Sample situation 1:

When the text is put to new Google Document, the following request body can be used.

```
requests = [
    {"insertText": {"location": {"index": 1}, "text": "\nถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ"}}
]
```

- When your current request body is used for the new Google Document, an error occurs at `{"insertText": {"location": {"index": 1}, "text": "\n"}}`. Because `\n` with `"index": 1` cannot be put to the 2 byte character.

#### Sample situation 2:

When the text is put to the Google Document including the texts of the Thai characters, the following request body can be used.

```
requests = [
    {"insertText": {"location": {"index": 2}, "text": "\nถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ"}}
]
```

- `"index": 2` is used for the existing 2 byte characters.
- In this case, if the text of `ถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ` has already been existing to the first paragraph, the additional text of `\nถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ` splits the existing texts like `ถ\nถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ`. By this, 2 byte character cannot be put to the 1st index to Document with existing 2 byte character. Unfortunately, in the current stage, I think that this is due to the issue of Google side.
- If the text of `sample`, which is 1 byte character, has already been existing to the first paragraph, the additional text of `\nถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับ` is put like `\nถ้ามีลูกแล้วไม่ส่งเรียนพิเศษอะไรเลย จะเป็นอะไรไหมครับsample`.

#### Reference:

- [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a partial solution, but I am struggling to understand also _why_ the error is occurring.  In my code, the newline is put _before_ any of the 2-byte characters, not 'in the center' of them.  (You can even try `{"insertText": {"location": {"index": 0}, "text": "\n"}}`, with `0` rather than `, which will still fail.)

Comment: @Brad Solomon Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to replicate the issue, it is required to confirm the sample Google Document. So can you provide it? Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.